# Unsubscribing from valuechanged doesnt work

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code to subscribe

```
    reference.Child("power").OrderByValue().LimitToLast(50).ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
```

then

```
 void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.DatabaseError != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(args.DatabaseError.Message);
            return;
        }
        looperr = 49;
        snapo = args.Snapshot;
        showplayername.text = playername;
        showpower.text = calco.totalpower.ToString("###");
        looper();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("power");
        reference.OrderByValue().LimitToLast(50).ValueChanged -= HandleValueChanged;
    }
```

however it still send changes after unsubscribing i tried moving the unsubscribe method and delay it but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the subscriptions may be instance based. If that is the case, you'll need to keep the  query in a variable, and subscribe/unsubscribe on the same variable.

So something like:

```
var query = reference.OrderByValue().LimitToLast(50)

...

query.ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged

...

query.ValueChanged -= HandleValueChanged
```

Comment: thanks, it worked 
although i had to define a public query instead of var because both code blocks are in different functions